# How do I fix invalid literal for int() with base 10 error in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, int, jupyter-notebook, valueerror

This is the error that is showing up whenever i try to convert the dataframe to int.

**("invalid literal for int() with base 10: '260,327,021'", 'occurred at index Population1'**

Everything in the df is a number. I assume the error is due to the extra quote at the end but how do i fix it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I run this

```
int('260,327,021')
```

and get this

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-448-a3ba7c4bd4fe> in <module>()
> ----> 1 int('260,327,021')
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '260,327,021'
> ```

I assure you that not everything in your dataframe is a number.  It may look like a number, but it is a string with commas in it.

You'll want to replace your commas and then turn to an `int`

```
pd.Series(['260,327,021']).str.replace(',', '').astype(int)

0    260327021
dtype: int64
```

Comment: oh wow. Thank you so much! So this means i have to replace everything then. Every number in the df looks like the one i gave.

Comment: @Caribgirl yes!  Unless you read it from a file, then you can pass a parameter to the `read_csv` function, namely `thousands=','`

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! omg. I have been trying to fix this for hours! Thank You!!!!!

Answer (score 14):

Others might encounter the following issue, when the string is a float:

```
    >>> int("34.54545")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '34.54545'
```

The workaround for this is to convert to a float first and then to an int:

```
>>> int(float("34.54545"))
34
```

Or pandas specific:

```
df.astype(float).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 7):

I solved the error using [pandas.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)

In your case,

```
data.Population1 = pd.to_numeric(data.Population1, errors="coerce")
```

'data' is the parent Object.

After that, you can convert float to int as well

```
data.Population1.astype(int)
```

Comment: This solved my issue of having a space int the values. Thank you. I also had to add df['series'].fillna(0).astype(int) aka .fillna(0) to get rid of the NaNs for my particular issue.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was a bit different case.

I loaded my dataframe as such:

```
my_converter = {'filename': str, 'revision_id': int}

df = pd.read_csv("my.csv", header=0, sep="\t", converters=my_converter)
```

becuase `head -n 3 my.csv` looked like so:

```
"filename"     "revision_id"
"some_filename.pdf"     "224"
"another_filename.pdf"     "128"
```

However, down thousands of lines, there was an entry like this:

```
 "very_\"special\"_filename.pdf"     "46"
```

which meant that I had to specify the escape character to the `read_csv()`. Else, it would try to cast `special` as `int` for the `revision_id` field and generate the error.

So the correct way is to:

```
df = pd.read_csv("my.csv", header=0, sep="\t",  escapechar='\\', converters=my_converter)
```