# How do I put all the rows that don't have a certain value into a dataframe?(jupyter notebook/google colab)

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

under ileads_address I'm trying to create a DF that only prints out all the rows that don't have 0.0. Is there anyway to code that?

I tried doing this

```
df5 = df4[~df4['ileads_address'] == 0]
```

[Sample CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH6ld.png)

Comment: added a solution. did it worked for you?

Comment: Yes it did thank you. Am I able to ask a different question?

Comment: great! sure go ahead if its related. otherwise you can open another question

Comment: Ok so the reason why I wanted to take out all the 0's because I was having trouble turning "ileads_address" into an int representation(take out the .0). IT keeps giving an error "IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer". It still gives me that error after I do df5['ileads_address'] = df5['ileads_address'].astype(int)

Comment: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer : It means some of the data is NaN. that result in error. you can convert that to 0 using fillna(0). prior to it check  like  df4[df4['ileads_address'].isnull()] for such rows

Comment: Managed to convert the data that is NaN to 0 but I'm now getting a Value Error, "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5017.0'

Comment: Check this out. Go through all the answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858595/how-do-i-fix-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-error-in-pandas#43858649

Comment: How would I call upon this code : "pd.Series(['260,327,021']).str.replace(',', '').astype(int)" but with my df5? I tried all the other answers and they didn't work.

Comment: i suggest you to share the data as text in the question. follow guidelines here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df4[df4['ileads_address'] != 0]
```